# Electron-forge to Electron-builder - "Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document."

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

This message is already present when I launch my Electron app since I build with Electron-builder.

Config files seems fine, do a release works, but I can't resolve this error.

I'm trying to fix this issues or to launch the app to check if the builder is working.